# Scope of Variable in Jenkins pipeline between Stage and Post actions

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline, jenkins-groovy

i have following pipeline code created for automating test runs in which im facing an issue where the variable defined in Stage section and trying to use value of that variable in post action section, but problem comes here where the value of variable comes as null. So i suspect this something related to the variable scope. Could someone please guide me in this problem?

Please find my code snippet

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
env.JenkinsAgent = 'JenkinsNode'
env.StartTime
env.EndTime

pipeline 
    {
    agent {label """'${JenkinsAgent}'"""} 
    stages 
        { 
       stage ('Execute Test Run & Notify Users')
            {
            steps 
                {
                script 
                    {
                    env.StartTime = new Date ()
                    env.StartTime = (env.StartTime.getTime())
                    echo "Epoch Timestamp - Start time is: ${StartTime} "
                    bat label: '', returnStdout: true,script: "Run.bat"
                    echo "LoadTest Execution completed" 
                    env.EndTime = new Date ()
                    env.EndTime = (env.EndTime.getTime())
                    echo "Epoch Timestamp - End time is: ${EndTime} "
                    }
                }
            post // action to be taken based on the above steps success or failure
            {
            success
                {
                script 
                    { 
                    currentBuild.result = 'SUCCESS'
                    echo "Load Test executed Successfully"
                    mail bcc: ' ',
                    body: """Test completed. Start time is ${StartTime} and End time is ${EndTime}""", 
                    cc: """${EmailCC}""", 
                    from: 'Jenkins', 
                    mimeType: 'text/html', 
                    replyTo: '',
                    subject: """Jenkins Alert: Stage : Execute Load Test completed""", 
                    to: """${EmailTo}"""
                    }
                }
            failure
                {
                script 
                    {
                    currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'
                    error('Aborting the build.')
                    }
                }   
            }    
        }
    } // stages  
} //pipeline
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use variables between stages, you need to define them as global variables. Refer to the following pipeline.

```
// Global variable
def globalVar = "Initial Value"

pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                script {
                    echo "Printing initial values : ${globalVar}"
                    // Reassigning a value
                    globalVar = "New value"
                }
            }

            post {
                success {
                    echo "${globalVar}"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, if you see i have already declared the variable at the top before pipeline, hope it has a global scope and then i used for manipulation in stage and then trying to use manipulated value from stage in Post section.

Comment: After adding with def before variable, the rest worked as much with my code. can you please help me to understand why is this? 

my code has

env.StartTime and env.EndTime and i assumed this like a Environment variable which will be global to access everywhere in Jenkins pipeline. But when i giving it as def variablename only worked. Kindly help me to understand the difference that will be useful to understand the issue, Thanks a lot..!

Comment: @Chandru First try to understand why we use environment variables. For example, environment variables are used to externally change the behavior of a program. If you take the Jenkins server itself on Jenkins startup If you set the environment variable JENKINS_OPTS you can change the behavior of the server.  In the same way, if you want to set an environment variable so you can use them in `sh` block then you should be setting them. What you are trying to create are variables.

Comment: the issue here is if you set them global, if  multiple stages manipulate that variable in  parallel workflow, you have race conditions.  so  it would be good to be able scope locally to a stage (which is easy enough), but also have that available by the post actions of that stage(which is unclear)